# How do I add a photo to a form without InfoPath?

Tags: 2013, infopath, form

I on a 2013 site. I would like to add a photo to a form that was created within SP without using InfoPath. Is this possible? here is an example. [image]

This was created using InfoPath. Any information on how to do this without InfoPath would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CEWP at the top of your page.  Store the Image in an image library so SharePoint can get it.  Then, use HTML in the CEWP to make your header with the image.  Should work just fine.

Comment: Im not trying to add a header to a page. Im trying to try to add a header to a form. When i hit "New Item" and the form opens I want an image at the top of the form.

Comment: Right, edit the page, and put a CEWP on the top of the form, then do as instructed.  It will work.

Comment: is the form created using infopath ?

Comment: @lazoDev you cant add a CEWP to a form.

Comment: No the default New/Edit/Disp/Allitems Item form. Edit that page and put the web part on top.

Comment: @Nikhil unfortunately no. I know how to do this very easy with InfoPath but I was told to try to find a way to do it without InfoPath. So far I haven't found anything. I'm currently trying to code it directly to the page using designer but no luck so far.

Comment: yes you can put this at the end of your url to open the page in edit view ?ToolPaneView=2 then add your web part.  I am currently doing this to 7 custom form I have made using the default I know you can do it for a fact.

Comment: I'm going to give it a shot and i will report back.

Comment: make your URL like this http://mysite/list/mylist/EditForm.aspx?ToolPaneView=2

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! This worked perfectly. Your help was much appreciated!!!!! I would up vote but i don't have the rep yet.

Comment: anytime :) I work in SharePoint everyday like all of us.  I know how much of a bitch she can be :)  good luck to ya!

Comment: rolf . . i have upvoted ..

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood correctly :

1.Add all images to images doc lib .

2.Create a new list , add a column with "picture" type . while creating new item provide the url of picture from images library .

OR directly create a picture library and add items .

UPDATE :

1. When you click new item in list , it either can open in newform.aspx or editform.aspx .
2. Open the newform along the querystring ToolPaneview=2 .
   http://www.aad.com/sites/mikhil/Lists/MikhilTestList/NewForm.aspx?ToolPaneView=2
   3.The Newform page now opens in edit mode .
3. Add content editor webpart and write javascript to fetch the image .

Comment: I'm not trying to upload a photo to a library. I'm trying to add a photo to a form as a heading like in the photo above.

Comment: Are you ninja-ing my answer lol

Comment: my update is before you . . lol

Comment: http://ahmedmuneeb1.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/make-client-side-changes-in-sharepoint-lists-newform-aspx-or-editform-aspx/